# How do I make an array keep going?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an array keep on going as opposed to stopping on the last object, if I have sorted its elements how do I make it keep going ?

```
window.onload=nextcity;

var c = new Array(); 
c[0] = {cName:"Dresden"};
c[1] = {cName:"Belin"};
c[2] = {cName:"Frankfurt"};
c[3] = {cName:"Koln"};
c[4] = {cName:"Dusseldorf"};
c[5] = {cName:"Leipzig"};

c.sort();

var Citynum = 0;

function nextcity () {
  document.getElementById('cityoptions').innerHTML=c[Citynum].cName;
  Citynum ++;
}
```

To explain better, when a button is clicked I want the writing to change to a city name i.e. it would look something like this

`<`    `DRESDEN`    `>`

and when the arrow is clicked it will show a different name I don't want it to stop I want it to keep going.

Comment: what about a for loop? can you please put some more details to specify what you exactly need to do? It's quite broad to be honest

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Let us know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: `window.onload=nextcity;` will run your function `nextcity()` only once.. so you can't do it that way it is right now.. either you change your function to have a loop instead, or you change the event of your function to something that could make sense for that.. e.g `onclick` *of some element*

Comment: What do you mean by "keep going"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reset the `Citynum` counter to 0 once it reaches the size of `c`, making the list repeat:

```
function nextcity () {
  document.getElementById('cityoptions').innerHTML=c[Citynum].cName;
  Citynum ++;
  if (Citynum >= c.length)
    Citynum = 0;
}
```

Comment: also need a corresponding `function prevcity () { ...` to wrap the index in the same was when the _left_ button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { 
    document.getElementById('cityoptions').innerHTML=c[i].cName;
}
```

Comment: What's that going to do, just put the last item in the `cityoptions`?